# Script não está funcionando no IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Estou utilizando esse script no Chrome e ele funciona normalmente. Porém no IE 8 ou 9 não funciona. Coloquei um debugger e um alert para debugar, mas ele nem entra na funcão.

```
$(document).on("mousedown", '#CentroCusto_new option', function (event) {
    alert('oi');
    this.selected = !this.selected;
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Alguém sabe o motivo e como corrigir?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fp4WD/)

Comment: Tentou simplesmente retornar `false`em vez de setar o returnValue? O jQuery normaliza isso.

Comment: Outra coisa: você precisa estar com as dev tools do IE abertas, ou a primeira linha (`debugger`) vai dar pau.

Comment: O restante do programa funciona normalmente? (a parte que depende do jQuery, principalmente) Há algum outro código funcionando que utilize `on`? E um tiro no escuro: já tentou colocar seu *handler* no `body` ou algum outro elemento ancestral de `#CentroCusto_new`, em vez do `document`?

Comment: No IE ele não consegue nem entrar na função, nada dentro vai funcionar. @bfavaretto

Comment: Agora reparei que você está tentando pegar cliques em options. Por que não monitorar o change do select em vez disso?

Comment: Não funcionou no body. Coloco no option pois estou previnindo o comportamento padrão dele que é de desselecionar os outros ao clicar em um.

Comment: Creio que o ie não está aceitando o seletor

Comment: Sei que parece louco, mas experimente colocar um atributo `size` com valor numérico no seu select. Ver http://stackoverflow.com/a/3341779/825789

Comment: Não funcionou. To aqui sem saber o que tentar mais.

Comment: Criei um JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/fp4WD/

Comment: Eu estou em Linux neste momento, mas ao que me recordo, o IE não dispara o evento de `click` na `option` mas sim na `select`. Experimenta anexar o evento de `click` à tua `select` e recolhe o valor da `option`: [JSFiddle Aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/4xBvD/)

Comment: Testei no IE8 e IE9, não tem como você capturar o evento de click em um option, mas tem como capturar no select, no evento não vai te dizer quem está selecionado, mas podes descobrir com nas propriedades do elemento.

Comment: em relação ao seu JSFiddle, vejo que o IE tem problemas com a versão do jQuery 1.10.1, veja o erro que ele dá no console: `SCRIPT5: Acesso negado.
jquery-1.10.1.js, linha 1513 Caractere 2
SCRIPT5009: '$' não está definido 
_display, linha 21 Caractere 5
`

Comment: acreditem ou não, a ordem que voce chama os scripts no seu html interferem em funcionar ou não nos IE's, outra coisa, cada função precisa de um arquivo separado por que se não o IE se perde, descubri isso quando tinha um arquivo de funções Jquery de mais de 100 linhas e o IE nem lia o arquivo...

Comment: Vi esse problema no stackoverflow em ingles, será que da pra adaptar meu código com o código da resposta aceita? tentei mas acho que não da, pois necessito do prevent default da option. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341740/click-event-for-option-doesnt-work-in-ie

Comment: COnsegui resolver este problema? Olhando rápido a ideia que me ocorre é: http://jsfiddle.net/k4G3J/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O IE realmente não deixa entende a seleção através da option.

O ie entende o seletor $(":selected"), que pode ser util em alguns casos, mas não neste em específico.

Answer (score 7):

No seguimento do [comentário que havia deixado ontem na tua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9090/script-nao-esta-funcionando-no-ie#comment15488_9090), hoje tive oportunidade de testar e realmente o Internet Explorer não dispara o evento de `click` na `option` do elemento `select` mas sim no próprio `select`.

Assim, para poderes despoletar determinada acção quando uma `option` e alterada, podes anexar o evento `click` à `select` e procurar pela `option` que está seleccionada para agires em conformidade com a mesma:

[**Demonstração no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/qCtUd/)

```
// anexar evento de click à select
$(document).on("click", 'select', function (e) {

    // apanha option que recebeu click
    var $opt = $(this).find(":selected");

    // fazer algo com o valor da mesma
    alert($opt.attr("value"));
});
```

Comment: Pesquisando também encontrei esta forma. Mas não deu para adapta-la ao meu codigo usando preventDefault. +1 pois pode ser util em outros casos

Comment: Mas qual o teu objectivo especificamente? O comportamento-por-defeito de uma caixa de selecção múltipla é seleccionar algo ou realizar uma selecção múltipla. É a selecção o que pretendes evitar?

Comment: O comportamento default é que no clique do mouse você só seleciona uma option de cada vez. Precisando pressionar Ctrl e clicar para ele selecionar mais de um. Quero ter o mesmo resultado do Ctrl + Click apenas clicando com o mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Isso funciona ?

```
    jQuery("#CentroCusto_new option").on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('oi');
        this.selected = !this.selected;
        return false;
    });
```

ou algo parecido com isso ?

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
alert( "Handler for .change() called." ); 
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/change/